# Copying Event Viewer Logs and Deleting them on Successful Copy Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy, erase, event-viewer

So im having some issues using powershell to get this code to work

```
Copy-Item "%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx" "C:\CommFiles\LogFile_$(get-date -uformat %d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S).txt"
if(-not $?) { 
    Write-Warning "Copy Failed" 
    } else {
    Remove-Item "%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"
    }
```

the goal is to copy the event log and save it to a location so i can audit them on future dates, but the problem i keep running into is that im getting an error saying that the file path is non-existent. maybe i have some syntax errors or something as well? im pretty new to powershell so theres alot of room for improvement for me, can anyone help?

Comment: In PowerShell syntax, `%SystemRoot%` is not expanded as you might think. Use `$env:SystemRoot` instead

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try printing `"%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"`.

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> Write-Host "%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"
```

Environment variables aren't expanded in Powershell with `%%` like they are in explorer and cmd. Powershell variables are expanded with `$` like they do in bash and some other languages, in addition to that, environemnt variables are stored in powershell on a separate `PSDrive` which is a special drive for powershell. You can see some of the drives with `Get-PSDrive`

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> Get-PSDrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
Alias                                  Alias
C                  95.34         22.75 FileSystem    C:\                                                      Users\Kai
Cert                                   Certificate   \
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan
```

And you can get variables from the `alias:` drive like so:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> echo "$alias:ac"
Add-Content
```

And for environment variables like `%SystemRoot%` you would take it like so:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> Write-Host "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
```

You can view all of the objects in each of these drives by doing this:

```
Get-ChildItem env:
Get-ChildItem Alias:
#etc.
```

and you can interact with them the same way you usually do with normal drives.

---

Taking this into account, your script would work like this:

```
Copy-Item "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx" "C:\CommFiles\LogFile_$(get-date -uformat %d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S).txt"
if(-not $?) { 
    Write-Warning "Copy Failed" 
} else {
    Remove-Item "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"
}
```

Comment: so i ran the changes you provided but i found a new issue now and im getting back an error that says '''Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx: The process cannot access the file
'C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx' because it is being used by another process.''' is there a proper way i can get it to be deleted on successful copy?

Comment: Try using the `-force` switch of `remove-item` or try running as administrator too like `Remove-Item "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx" -force` and this would be a different question since it is different than the post here.